# The maximum area of the uniqueness of the Cauchy problem for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, cauchy-problem

Help me please.
How to find the maximum area of the uniqueness of the Cauchy problem
$$u_{xx}-u_{xy}-2u_{yy}+3u_x-6u_y=0,$$
$$u|_{x=0, y>0}=e^{-y},\\ u_x|_{x=0, y>0}=e^{-y}.$$

---

I found the solution by changing variables from the characteristic equation $dy^2+dxdy-2dx^2=0$ and canonicalization.
$$u_{\psi\phi}+u_{\phi}=0,\; \phi=y-x,\; \psi=y+2x.$$
$$u(x,y)=e^{-y-2x}(3x+1).$$
But I can't figure out how to find this area from the characteristics.

---

It's true that this is the area $\{(x,y):y-x>0,y+2x>0\}$? That is an area where, through any point are two characteristic lines intersect $\{(0,y):y>0\}$.